# Add 2 click event on a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a html page, which will include a html page from another third party party.

In the third party code, there is a span that will calling a `jQuery` function from the third party as well.

The code will be as follow:

```
<span class="swatch" onclick="pplrColor(this,0)">ABC</span>
```

This code is out of control for me. However, I would like to run some other function after the `pplrColor()` function.

I am thinking to make another `onclick` event as follow, unfortunately, it doesn't work. (Maybe jQuery not allow to have double click event on one single html element.)

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("swatch")[0];

p.onclick = function(){
    alert("Finaly!");
}
```

Or is there any method exist something like .after() event in `jQuery` ? Or there is another better way to do this.

Comment: you should be using add addEventListener (not going to fix the order issue)

Comment: Does your code ***have*** to run after the `pplrColor()` function?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , yes, when user click on the span, it will run the pplrColor() function, which is from third party. And I am wish to run another my own function after this pplrColor() function.

Comment: code shows `swatch` and you look up `mywatch`.....

Comment: Are any events raised when the third party code has completed and the `span` is added to the DOM?

Comment: Is `pplrColor()` asynchronous? We are have no clue what it does so you have to give more details.

Comment: @epascarello, just edit my code to `swatch`.

Comment: When you bind with addEventListener, it will call that method after pplrColor has been called. It does not mean `pplrColor` is done running. We have no clue what is in the "black box". If it is asynchronous, then what ever library needs to provide events and the click is useless. Since we have no clue what your code does we really can not help.

Comment: pplrColor must be global (set on window) since it's referenced inline in the html.  You could store a reference to pplrColor (const origPplrColor = window.pplrColor), and then replace window.pplrColor with your own custom function.  In your custom function call origPplrColor whenever you want.